# Twist values for robot insanely large

Tags: ros, catkin-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I am making a robot based off of a wheelchair. When I try to run the bot with the teleop_twist_keyboard node I have to turn up the speed to over 20 in order for the motors to move and then they run extremely quickly. Is this normal? All of the programs I have tried for teleoperation have been in the range of +/- 1.5 or less for all axises. The github repo with the code is here: https://github.com/kk6axq/ros_arduino_bridge.git. Thanks for helping a beginner get on in ROS!
Thanks,
luketheduke

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205718/twist-values-for-robot-insanely-large/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is very high. Units on Twist should be in m/s (see [rep 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)) 20m/s is ~ 44mph which is a little fast for any wheelchair type application.

Requiring a command that high suggests that your platform's controller is not controlling for speed properly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-03-24**:
Could you take quick look through thew github repo and see if you could locate the problem?
Thanks,
Luketheduke